# Fatal error when activating CiviCRM fails and throws up catchable fatal error

Tags: wordpress

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to CiviCRM_WP_REST\Autoloader::add_source() must be an instance of CiviCRM_WP_REST\string, string given, called in /var/sites/b/caftest.site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 691 and defined in /var/sites/b/caftest.site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/wp-rest/Autoloader.php on line 64

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the CiviCRM WP REST API Wrapper plugin installed?
If so,try disabling that as it's not required with newer versions of Civicrm